# What to do when an application is not in a state that it can be tested for a scenario?

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am writing step definitions for scenario's described in Cucumber.
So If I am testing a scenario of liking a comment on a post.

Should I make sure that there will be a comment and a post in the first place in the steps only?

Or my test should catch such scenario and give a message in the log ?

I am using Cucumber-JVM as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well typically a good test technique is to test positives.  It's a good idea to write your test to the future feature that will come out.  In your case, write your selenium test to make sure that you are able to like your comment on a post.

Ideally, when that feature comes out, the test will already be written, and will go from a failing state to a passing state.

Even more ideally, it's a good idea to have a seperate dvl environment from your production, that way you can test on your dvl environment, and then just point your tests to production once that feature is released.

Comment: But my question is, should my test create a post and a comment on it before I check for like functionality ?

Comment: it depends on your acceptance criteria.  if your AC's say something like "after a post is created, then i should be able to 'like' it."  If that's the case, then yes. your test should create it.  That's best because your test will be self-sufficient and not be dependent on a comment already existing.